# Displaying Nested Attribute Values on Index and Show Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display some Nested Attribute Values on my Index and Show Views. I've got it to the point where they appear on my show view but all of the values display in a single record. I think I might need to specify the ID somewhere but am unsure. Am I missing something in my controller? Everything seems to save fine.

**Controller**

```
class CertificationApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_certification_application, only: [:show]

  # GET /certification_applications
  # GET /certification_applications.json
  def index
   @certification_applications = CertificationApplication.all
  end

  # GET /certification_applications/1
  # GET /certification_applications/1.json
  def show
   @certification_applications = CertificationApplication.includes(:individuals)
  end

  private

  def set_certification_application
    @certification_application = CertificationApplication.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**View**

This is how I am displaying it in my show view.

```
<p>
 <strong>Individual receiving certification:</strong>
 <% @certification_applications.each do |ca| %>
   <% ca.individuals.each do |i| %>
     <%= i.email %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a break and got it working not long after with show. Just a few adjustments did the trick.

Changed this part of my controller:

```
def show
 @certification_applications = CertificationApplication.includes(:individuals)
end
```

to

```
def show
 @certification_applications = CertificationApplication.includes(:individuals).find(params[:id])
end
```

I am assuming this allows the attributes to match with the correct ID.

and my view from

```
 <% @certification_applications.each do |ca| %>
  <% ca.individuals.each do |i| %>
   <%= i.email %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% @certification_applications.individuals.each do |ca| %>
   <%= ca.name %>
   <%= ca.email %>
<% end %>
```

Will need to determine how to get it working with Index but this is a good start.

Comment: _"I am assuming this allows the attributes to match with the correct ID."_ - You don't need to assume anything. There are guides, you know, to _guide_ you. See https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class.

Comment: You don't even need to `find` certification_application in your action `show`. You are already doing it in `before_action` `set_certification_application`. Expect for the `includes` part, which i think you can move to the before filter itself.

Comment: Removing `find` gives me a NoMethodError in CertificationApplications#show. Moreover, it says `undefined method 'individuals'`.

Comment: This was a pretty good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321845/correctly-displaying-nested-models-in-my-show-view